# Inequality for $s\in(1,2)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $p>1$ be a real number and $1<s<2$ be a real number. Then does the following inequality hold:
$
(s^p-1)-(s-1)^p\leq c(p)(s-1)
$
where $c(p)$ is a constant depending on $p$.

Comment: The interval mentioned in the title is not the one mentioned in the body of the question.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I don't have a complete solution yet. But I did some numerical and graphical experimentations that suggest that the claim is true.

First, I substituted $s=1+x$, so the desired inequality becomes $(1+x)^p-1-x^p\le c(p)\cdot x$.

Let's consider the function $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{(1+x)^p-1-x^p}{x}$ on $0<x<1$ with $p>1$.

By graphing, I could see that there's a critical value of $p=2$:

- for $1<p<2$, $f(x)$ is decreasing, attaining a maximum as $x\to0$, and the maximum is always less than $2$, so $c(p)=2$ would work.
- for $p=2$, $f(x)=2$ is a constant function, so $c(p)=2$ works again.
- for $p>2$,  $f(x)$ is increasing, attaining a maximum as $x\to1$. That maximum value is $c(p)=f(1)=2^p-2$.

Of course, as I said, this is not a complete proof yet, because I haven't worked out how to prove that $f(x)$ is decreasing or increasing in those two cases. But I hope this helps and you can take it from here.

Comment: I was also strucked by the task and tried solving it using elementary-high-school math. Is this useful:$$(s-1)(s^{p-1}-s^{p-2}+\ldots+ s(-1)^{p-2}+(-1)^{p-1})-(s-1)^p$$$$=(s-1)\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}s^{p-1-i}(-1)^i-\sum_{i=0}^p{p\choose i}s^{p-i}(-1)^i$$
$$(s-1)\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}s^{p-1-i}(-1)^i-(-1)^p-\sum_{1=0}^{p-1}{p\choose i}s^{p-i}(-1)^i=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\Bigg(\frac{s-1}{s}-{p\choose i}\Bigg)s^{p-i}(-1)^i-(-1)^p=$$$$s^p\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\Bigg(\frac{s-1}{s}-{p\choose i}\Bigg)s^{-i}(-1)^i-(-1)^p=s^p\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\Bigg(\frac{s-1}{s}-{p\choose i}\Bigg)\Big(-\frac{1}{s}\Big)^i-(-1)^p?$$

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya: This was my first thought too.. until I read the question more carefully. This factorization of $s^p-1$ works only when $p$ is a positive integer. But in the given question it doesn't have to be; instead, it can be any real (greater than $1$, as given, of course).

Comment: thank you very much for reminding! (:

Comment: I have an argument. Please comment if you have any doubt. Suppose by contradiction the result does not hold. Then there exists $s_0\in(1,2)$ such that for all $c(p)$ one has the inequality $s_{0}^p-1-(s_{0}-1)^p>c(p)(s_0-1)$. Since this holds for every $c(p)$, one can choose $c(p)$ large enough such that $s_{0}^p-1-(s_{0}-1)^p>c(p)(s_0-1)$ does not hold. Hence the result is true.